# Customized scrollbar for self-coded HTML and CSS website

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I am currently searching for a way to customize my scrollbar for my website and experimented a bit with the options today.

I want to make the scrollbar track not only invisible, but... "inexistent" and only the thumb to appear on the final site. Seems like, for some time, that was possible by setting "overflow: overlay" in the body tag of the corresponding CSS document, and then setting the scrollbar track color to invisible. Or at least, something like that. Then the "handle" would appear on top of the website's content, which could be a huge timesaver when designing. But now, this option does not work anymore.

[ARC](https://www.thisisarc.com/) did it basically exactly the way I want it to look, in a more custom manner. My search about alternative methods like their one to accomplish that did not result in anything useful.

Can please somebody try to understand and explain to me, how they did that? I already took a look at the HTML and CSS of ARC's site, but couldn't yet figure things out...
Maybe there's some JS in the whole idea as well? If so, it wouldn't be a problem, I guess...

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: ::-webkit-scrollbar is most of what we got these days for modifying the visuals.

Comment: yep, I already tried that. but it seems like it's not possible to get to what I want with that. and... well, it is only for webkit browsers.

Comment: You'd be correct it's a bit messy. Do check however different browsers on PC/Apple/Mobile. You'll see browsers have their own way of dealing with this. Some decide on background color and other CSS factors.

Comment: ARC achieves the appearance of an invisible scrollbar track and a scroll thumb that expands when hovered over by adding a custom scrollbar division (it’s added at the end of the page using jQuery). The parent divisions are set to `overflow: hidden` so there are no browser scrollbars. The content division `section class="main-content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1689465218615_102"` is translated in the Y direction based on the scroll position. There is also inertial scrolling (a.k.a. momentum scrolling) added to the transform calculation. There are GitHub repositories for scrollbars that may be helpful.

Comment: @RichDeBourke Yes, that looks like it is the right thing. So I took a look at the JS ([here](https://www.thisisarc.com/s/new_custom_js_5.js)) and searched for "scrollbar", there I think I could find something. And I found a GitHub repo, is [that](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/) one of those you mean?

Comment: Yes, the malihu scrollbar plugin would be a potential starting point. You might also want to check out some of the [branches}(https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-malihu-scrollbar). You’ll have to adjust the styles to get the look you want, but it has the general format and momentum scrolling.